# Closed form solution for a quadratic program in matrix form with inequality constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, constraints, quadratic-programming

Is there a closed form solution for the following quadratic program with inequality constraint? Let $P \in \mathbb{S}^n_{++}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $B$, $F \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ two non-square matrices for $k \geq n$. $F \geq 0$ is non-negative. Also let $R \in V_k(F_n)$ be the stiefel matrix such that $R^T R = Id_k$. We consider the following quadratic program in $X$ and $Y$. It should be really easy to solve, but I am interested in the closed form which is easier for me to analyze.

$$\min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}, Y\in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}} ||P^{\frac{1}{4}}X||^2_F+tr(B^TX)$$

$$Y+F \geq 0$$
$$RY = X$$

The lagrangian is $$L(X,Y, \Gamma, U) = ||P^{\frac{1}{4}}X||^2_F+tr(B^TX) +tr(\Gamma^T(Y+F))+tr(U^T(RY-X)),$$

with the gradient

$$\nabla_{X, Y}L(X,Y, \Gamma, U) =     \begin{pmatrix}
        2P^{\frac{1}{2}}X +  B -U \\
        \Gamma + R^TU \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, set $X = -\frac{1}{2} P^{-\frac{1}{2}}V$, $V = B-U$, $Y = 0$, and use the fact that $\frac{1}{2}tr(V^TP^{-\frac{1}{2}}V) = \frac{1}{2}||P^{-\frac{1}{4}}V||^2_F$, we derive the dual problem

$$\max_{U, V \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}, \Gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}} -\frac{1}{4}||P^{-\frac{1}{4}}V||^2_F+tr(\Gamma^TF) $$

$$\Gamma \geq 0$$
$$U-B = V$$
$$\Gamma + R^TU = 0$$

I am wondering if this is possible to just look at the KKT condition for the primal and dual and derive a reasonable closed form solution. The KKT conditions are

- $Y+F \geq 0$
- $RY = X$
- $\Gamma \geq 0$
- $U-B = V$
- $\Gamma + R^TU = 0$
- $2P^{\frac{1}{2}}X +  B -U = 0$
- $tr(\Gamma^T (Y+F)) = 0$

Comment: What does it mean for a nonsquare matrix to be non-negative? Is it non-negative definite (somehow?) or are its elements non-negative?

Comment: The elements are non-negative

Comment: You can convert this problem by vectorization into LS with inequality constraints. Check out the sections 8 and 9 in http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/69/134/CS-TR-69-134.pdf. But this document converts the problem into Linear Complementarity Problem, which does not have analytical solutions. In general, I doubt that you can get a closed form solution to your problem.